# Variables in Automator is not working?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

I'm trying to set variables in Automator but apparently it's not working?
It only outputs the latest variable; "Var2". What am I doing wrong?

This is what I'm trying to do

- Ask for text
- Set value of variable: Var1
- Ask for text
- Set value of variable Var2
- Get value of variable Var1
- Get value of variable Var2
- Run Shell script (as arguments):

for f in "$@"

do

echo "$1" "$2"

done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following **Automator** *workflow* works for me with the following *actions*, and make note of the **Options** *settings*:

- **Ask for Text**
- **Set Value of Variable**

  - **Variable: [Var1]**
- **Ask for Text**

  - **Options**

    - **[√] Ignore this action's input**
- **Set Value of Variable**

  - **Variable: [Var2]**
- **Get Value of Variable**

  - **Variable: [Var1]**
  - **Options**

    - **[√] Ignore this action's input**
- **Get Value of Variable**

  - **Variable: [Var2]**
- **Run Shell Script**

  - **Shell: [/bin/bash]            Pass input: [as arguments]**

    ```
    echo "$1" "$2"
    ```

In the **Results** *pane* of the **Run Shell Script** *action* it shows what was typed in both **Ask for Text** *actions*, which were of course set to the **Set Value of Variable** *actions*.

For example, I typed "**This is Var1**" and "**This is Var2**" respectively, and the **Results** *pane* of the **Run Shell Script** *action* showed:

```
This is Var1 This is Var2
```

---

Note in the image below that I did not check the **[] Require an answer** *check box* in the **Ask for Text** *action's* **Options**, however this was just for testing and I did add text in each instance. For the real thing, you may want to check that *check box*.

Also note that by checking the **[√] Ignore this action's input** *check box* in the given *actions*, there is a break between that *action* and the previous *action* as noted by no visible connection compared to the ones that are visibly connected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I have set up too.
Everything runs smoothly, but the shell script is not getting anything for "$2"
- If i use 'echo "$1" "$2"' I only get Var2.
- If I use 'echo "$1" "$2"' I get Var2 two times.
- If I use 'echo "$2" "$2"' I get nothing.
Results of both 'Get Value of Variable' actions are showing the correct value, it is just not passed on to the shell script.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I had "ignore this actions input" on Var2. I knew it had to be something silly. Thanks!